# How to save the data in a different column instead of replacing the data in same column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have one field on my form (field example name "completion_date"). This data is stored to table column "completion_date". When users edits the detail, data is overwritten in the backend table field as a default way of storing the data. How can I pass on the existing data in this column to a new column (completion_date_a) when the user saves a new date in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Littlefoots' answer is correct, but you could also do this in apex with very little work. Suppose your form items are P1_COMPLETION_DATE and P1_COMPLETION_DATE_A, both mapped to their respective database column. P1_COMPLETION_DATE_A is hidden. Add a computation to P1_COMPLETION_DATE_A with point "After Header" and type "Item". Pick P1_COMPLETION_DATE as item.

Now when you save the form, the value of P1_COMPLETION_DATE_A will be set to the value of P1_COMPLETION_DATE when it was selected.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a database trigger, e.g.

```
create or replace trigger trg_bu_date
  before update on your_table
  for each row
begin
  :new.completion_date_a := :old.completion_date;
end;
/
```